# How I can replace a underscore with an space inside a word starting with an special char in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string:

```
var str = "{view-map:{lonField_sad:!Longitude,latField:!Handicap_Accessible},currentView:!map}";
```

And I'm trying to replace the **ALL** the underscores with spaces for any word starting with exclamation sing (!) so the string should looks like this one:

```
var str = "{view-map:{lonField_sad:!Longitude,latField:!Handicap Accessible},currentView:!map}";
```

I spent a few hours trying to figure out how to do that without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [function replacement form](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/3a7pxmd2/)):

```
str.replace(/!\w+/g, function(x) { return x.replace(/_/g, ' '); })
```

Regexp `/!\w+/g` selects all words started with "!". After that we replace each word `x` with result of `x.replace(/_/g, ' ')`.

Comment: This will not work because `\w` include `_` as well.So this will never stop at `_`

Comment: @vks, I know, try this http://jsfiddle.net/w01ddxey/. It works, you just don't understand how.

Comment: coudlnt check the fiddle....newaz if you are so confident may i know wt's d logic?

Comment: @vks, check in dev tool console or this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/w01ddxey. I have explained logic in answer.

Comment: I've updated your code to replace all the underscore occurrences. http://jsfiddle.net/3a7pxmd2/

Comment: @Topicus, I have updated my answer with your corrections, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

`!([^_]+)_([^]+)`

and replace with `$1 $2`

```
var str = "{view-map:{lonField_sad:!Longitude,latField:!Handicap_Accessible},currentView:!map}";
console.log(str.replace(/!([^_]+)_([^]+)/g, "!$1 $2"));
```

Comment: JS code for that would be something like `str = str.replace(/!([^_]+)_([^]+)/g, ' ')`

Comment: @cloudfeet included before you commented :)

Comment: Ninja'd, darn you. :)

Comment: I believe `!` is also needed in replaced string.

Comment: I guess this only works when strings has one underscore but I need to replace all the occurrences. For instance, if instead of having  a underscore (Handicap_accessible) had two (Handicap_accesible_more) then the result would be Handicap accesible_more.

Answer (score 0):

```
(![^_]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF5fT5/57

```
var re = /(![^_]+)_([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/gm;
var str = '{view-map:{lonField_sad:!Longitude,latField:!Handicap_Accessible},currentView:!map}';
var subst = '$1 $2';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```